# Android in-app testing subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented subscriptions in my app and have the product listed on my developer Console.  Test purchases are not currently supported for subscription in-app items so I need to test using a real credit card - no problem for me.  Also I'm testing on a phone other than my developer phone because we are not allowed to test on our developer phone (can you make it any harder Google?)  Previously I successfully tested consumable products using this phone using a bogus -0999 credit card and this worked well.

Now when I try to buy a subscription, Google Play wants to use the -0999 credit card and it fails to be approved.  So I would like to change it to use a real credit card but I can't figure out how to do the.  How can I test with a real credit card?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

When you were testing your consumables, Google Play put that phoney credit card number into your Google Wallet Account.  Going into Google Wallet, deleting the phoney CC and entering a valid CC solves the problem.